# Libreoffice calc: countifs over two rows

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I have a table with dates in column A and strings in column B. I'd like the countifs function to count the cells where the weekday in column A is thursday and the corresponding cell in column B is empty. In pseudo code:

```
counter = 0
for i in {1..49}
    if weekday(Ai)=5 AND Bi=""
        counter = +1
```

Basically, I don't know what argument I have to give to the weekday-function in  `=countifs(A1:A49;weekday(?);B1:B49;"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT function. Try the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(A1:A49)=5)*(B1:B49=""))
```